# Gem for Google Analytics (Rails 3.2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, google-analytics

Can someone suggest the most commonly used Gems for Google Analytics.

We would need to access data via API.

(We are using Rails 3.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can see the list of Google Analytics GEMs in the order of their popularity:

https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Web_Analytics

Answer (score 0):

checkout this [gem](https://github.com/cparratto/trackable-click) for env sensitive tacking. It also supports facebook pixel placement.